# Java unable to ForEach an array list of a custom class (incompatible type)

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

When I attempt to foreach through an array list of objects of a custom class I get the following error: error:

"incompatible types: (object) cannot be converted to ArrayList."

After reading through several other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420331/what-causes-incompatible-types-java-lang-object-cannot-be-converted-in-a) I thought I was just missing casting or making the object type explicit in my declaration. However after fixing it the problems persists.

```
ArrayList<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();

for (final ArrayList room: roomList)
```

What am I missing? If it makes a difference I'm using [this](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/) online compiler as my IDE.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class SchedulingApplication
{
    ArrayList<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
    int roomCount = 0;
static class Meeting
{
    double startTime;
    double endTime;
}
static class Room
{
    int roomNumber = 0;
    ArrayList<Meeting> meetingList = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
}


void addNewMeeting(double start, double end)
{
    Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
    checkConflict(meeting);
    return;

}

void addNewRoom(int number)
{
    Room room = new Room();
    room.roomNumber = number;
    roomCount++;
    roomList.add(room);
}
int checkConflict(Meeting newMeeting)
{
    //boolean isScheduled = false;
    boolean isConflict = false;
    if (roomCount == 0)
    {
        roomCount++;
        return roomCount;
    }
    else
    {
            for (final ArrayList room: roomList)
            {
                isConflict = false;
                for (final ArrayList  oldMeeting: room.meetingList())
                {
                    //see if the new meeting starts during all of the old meetings in this room
                    if (newMeeting.startTime > oldMeeting.startTime && newMeeting.startTime < oldMeeting.endTime)
                    {
                        isConflict = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isConflict)
                {
                    //isScheduled = true;
                    return room.roomNumber();
                }
            }

    }

}

    public static void main (String[] args) {




}
```

}

Comment: Hint: Is `room` supposed to be an `ArrayList`?

Comment: The official term for this kind of loop is "enhanced for loop".  If you Google that, you should easily be able to find a tutorial that shows you the correct way to write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (Room room : roomList)` not `for (ArrayList room : roomList)`

Comment: This was it. I figured it was something simple. Thanks for the second eye!

Answer (score 2):

Your roomList arrayList carries data of type Room. So when you retrive data from that arrayList in the forEach loop, you need to receive it in a reference of Room type.

```
for (Room room: roomList){
    //your code
}
```